# How do I store and use the output regression formula which has been identified from stepAIC regression?

Tags: r, regression, predict

```
TestRegALL <- lm(RegV.DiffMoMChange.FIN$Y ~ RegVariables.FIN$A + RegVariables.FIN$B + RegVariables.FIN$C + RegVariables.FIN$D + RegVariables.FIN$E + RegVariables.FIN$F + RegVariables.FIN$G + RegVariables.FIN$H + RegVariables.FIN$I + RegVariables.FIN$J + RegVariables.FIN$K)

TestRegALL.stepAIC <- stepAIC(TestRegALL, directions = "both")
summary(TestRegALL.stepAIC)
```

The summary reveals a particular formula:

```
lm(formula = RegV.DiffMoMChange.FIN$Y ~ RegVariables.FIN$A + RegVariables.FIN$B + RegVariables.FIN$C + RegVariables.FIN$D + RegVariables.FIN$E + RegVariables.FIN$F + RegVariables.FIN$J + RegVariables.FIN$K)
```

w/o variables G, H, I

How do I store this formula to use for forecasting purposes?

As this output regression formula is likely to change over time with monthly updated data, I'd like to find out how I can write this on R script and use the updated formula for forecasting/prediction.

Comment: `TestRegALL.stepAIC$call` will return the selected formula from stepwise model selection by AIC.

Comment: To re-run the `model<- TestRegALL.stepAIC$call`, execute `eval(model)`.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to automatically calculate Y with the formula from 'TestRegALL.stepAIC$call' with future variables A,B,C,etc.? Cheers! @AdamQuek

Comment: Just update your data in the same format and `eval(model)` and you should be able to get it. Try subsetting your data and see if this option work. Also, consider working with a single data.frame or model.matrix... not very intuitive to call variables across two matrices (RegV.DiffMoMChange.FIN and RegVariables.FIN)

Comment: I wouldn't use the `eval` trick. The method `update` can be used to re-estimate a model on a new data set.

Comment: @JanvanderLaan `eval` is the most straightforward method given the way the regression formula was written. I definitely would have opted for the  `update` route if the regression formula was written more cleanly...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `update` to reestimate a model with new data and you can use `predict` to compute predictions from a model.

First, I would not use the name of the data.frame in the formula, but pass the data.frame using the `data` argument of `lm` (and most other modelling functions). Using a generated data set:

```
N <- 1000
traindata <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(N), A = rnorm(N), 
  B = rnorm(N), C = rnorm(N), D = rnorm(N))

model_0 <- lm(Y ~ A + B + C + D, data = traindata)
model_step <- MASS::stepAIC(model_0, direction = "both")
```

The advantage of passing the data.frame to `lm` using the `data` argument is that it is now possible to use the same formula for other data sets (with different names).

For example, to generate predictions for a new data set `testdata`:

```
N <- 500
testdata <- data.frame(A = rnorm(N), B = rnorm(N),
  C = rnorm(N), D = rnorm(N))

predict(model_step, newdata = testdata)
```

Re-estimate the model using a new data set using `update`:

```
N <- 1000
newdata <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(N), A = rnorm(N), B = rnorm(N), C = rnorm(N), D = rnorm(N))

model_new <- update(model_step, data = newdata)
```

`update` can also be used to modify the formula (e.g. add the coefficient C to the model:

```
model_new2 <- update(model_step, . ~ . + C)
```

You can use the method `formula` to extract the formula from a model. Below I use the formula from `model_0` to update `model_new` using `stepAIC`:

```
model_new_step <- MASS::stepAIC(model_new, formula(model_0), direction = "both")
```